# Android, force onLayoutChange function to execute once after it was assigned?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Just added a onLayoutChangeListener to my Textview, and it seems to be working perfectly, but some other views that rely on it afterwards (before any layoutchange actually happens) don't, because the inner function wasn't executed yet by that time, can I fake a layout change to force the inner function to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make another method, for example, `public void updateUI()` and put what you need in that.  Then you can just call that from `onLayoutChanged()` and anywhere else you want.

Comment: thing is, I'm using onLayoutChanged() dimensions, such as int left, int top, int right, etc. Can i retrieve those from elsewhere?

Comment: You can use `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredWidth()`.  I'm not sure about the top and left.